# How to add values on bar of grouped bar plot using mtext?

Tags: r, plot

How to write values on bars using `mtext`?

```
# Grouped Bar Plot
counts <- table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS",xlab="Number of Gears", col=c("darkblue","red"),legend = rownames(counts), beside=TRUE, horiz=TRUE)

mtext(counts )   # But position is not at each bar.
```

How can I put corresponding values on each bar plot?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, `mtext` is generally use for margins. Is there a reason you do not want to use `text`?

```
 bplt <- barplot(counts, 
                 main="Car Distribution by Gears and VS", xlab="Number of Gears", 
                 col=c("darkblue","red"), legend = rownames(counts), 
                 beside=TRUE, horiz=TRUE)

# variable 'bplt' is now a matrix of vertical bar positions on the y-axis

text(x= counts+0.3, y= bplt, labels=as.character(counts), xpd=TRUE)
# Needed to use xpd=TRUE because the xlimits were too narrow.
```

[image]

Comment: @Manish If this answer works fine for you (as you indicated in a comment to your own question) then you should accept the answer.